# How to loop through each line in a file PHP

Tags: php

I am making a redeem key page for educational purposes with PHP just to see what it is capable of. I am storing the keys in a txt file as such:

```
key1
key2
```

And so on.
I have tried the following to loop through the txt file, insert the values into and array and work off of there. Here is what I have:

```php
$gkey = $_GET["key"];

$file = fopen("./generatedkeys.txt", "a");
$generatedk = array();

// generate table from data in txt file
while(! feof($file)) {
   $generatedk[] = fgets($file);
}
    

foreach ($generatedk as $key){
   if ($key == hash("sha256", $gkey)){

      // Removing of key from data in txt file
      $contents = file_get_contents($file);
      $contents = str_replace($key, '', $contents);
      file_put_contents($file, $contents);
      fclose($file);

      $accfile = fopen("./accs.txt", "a");
      fwrite($accfile, hash("sha256", $key).",".hash("sha256", $hwid)."\n");

      break;
   }
}
```

The code above however doesn't seem to be working. The key is simply not detected and not removed from generatedkeys.txt. (Not sure if there is any errors since I cannot see any).
Is there any obvious mistakes?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's probably easier just to read the file into a string all-at-once and then `split` the string. Remember that the bulk of PHP's core functionality and function-library are just thin wrappers over the C standard library (and C doesn't make it easy to read files line-by-line as file IO is done using fixed-size buffers, not lines). The OOP stuff didn't get added until PHP5.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to be working" - Please edit your question and write the expected behaviour

Comment: Just use [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) instead. That will give you an array with each line as an array item, which seems to be what you're trying to manually do.

Comment: Undefined variable `$hwid`

Comment: Tip: file_get_contents() and file_put_contents() expect the file path

Comment: @berend I havnt posted the full code. $hwid is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will make some empty lines when erases key from file.
And you passed return value of fopen() as a parameter of file_get_contents(). the return value is resource on file, but file_get_contents() needs string(file path).

You can check following.

```
$gkey = $_GET["key"];

$file_path="./generatedkeys.txt";
$file = fopen($file_path, "a");
$generatedk = array();

// generate table from data in txt file
while(! feof($file)) {
   $generatedk[] = fgets($file);
}
fclose($file);

for($i=0; $i<count($generatedk); $i++){
   $key=$generatedk[$i];
   if ($key == hash("sha256", $gkey)){

      // Removing of key from data in txt file
      array_splice($generatedk, $i, 1);
      file_put_contents($file_path, implode("\n", $generatedk));

      $accfile = fopen("./accs.txt", "a");
      fwrite($accfile, hash("sha256", $key).",".hash("sha256", $hwid)."\n");
      fclose($accfile);

      break;
   }
}
```

I hope it will be working well.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just tried out your method but I get the following error:
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 134217736 bytes) 
This error is on line 33 at:
$generatedk[] = fgets($file);

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I found this line could occur an error. you can use file_get_contents() instead of fget(). Try to use this code snippet instead while loop.                                                               $contents=file_get_contents($file_path); $generatedk=explode("\n", $contents);

Comment: Hmm, now I seem to be getting this error:
Fatal Error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in (file path)

Comment: if the error is occurred at file_get_contents() function, you can use 
file($file_path) function. please refer to [help](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). If you can share your screen, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Dont worry! I managed to get it working thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should make the process simpler, using `file` to read the whole file in one go into an array and then using `array_search()` to find if the key exists (it returns false if not found, so `!== false`).

Then if found, it just appends the used key to the other file, unsets the array entry for the key and overwrites the original file...

```
$gkey = $_GET["key"];

$generatedk = file("./generatedkeys.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

if ( ($entry = array_search(hash("sha256", $gkey), $generatedk)) !== false )    {
    // Add key used, with whatever content you want
    file_put_contents("./accs.txt", $gkey.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    // Remove found key from list in input file
    unset($generatedk[$entry]);
    // Overwrite input file with adjusted array
    file_put_contents("./generatedkeys.txt", implode(PHP_EOL, $generatedk));
}
```