# PHP count and seperate text from text file

Tags: php, text, count

Let's say inside the text file is this information:

```
<Amanda> Hi there, how are you?
<Jack> Hi, im fine 
.
.
.
.
<Jack> see you later
```

I want to count the words each user have said the output should be for example like this

```
Amanda: 50
Jack: 40
```

First I want to not count the `<Amanda>` or `<Jack>` and next I want to count every words they said and insert it to variables Amanda and Jack

This is what I have done

```
    $usercount1 = 0;
    $usercount2 = 0;  

    //Opens a file in read mode  
    $file = fopen("logfile.txt", "r");  
    //Gets each line till end of file is reached  
    while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {  
        //Splits each line into words
        $words = explode(" ", $line);  
        $words = explode("<Amanda>", $line);  
        //Counts each word  
        $usercount1 = $usercount1 + count($words);  
    }

    while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {  
        //Splits each line into words  
        $words = explode(" ", $line);
        //Counts each word  
        $usercount2 = $usercount2 + count($words);  
    }
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you show your PHP code?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65370800/how-to-loop-through-each-line-in-a-file-php

Comment: First I want to not count the <Amanda> or <Jack> and next is I want to count every words they said and insert it to variables Amanda and Jack

Comment: If you don't want it to count "Amanda" and "Jack", you could use `str_replace` to remove them from the string before you explode it and count the words.

Comment: If every line starts with a name in angle-brackets that you want to leave out, you could just subtract one from the count.

Comment: Show us what you've tried to solve the issue. To me, if every line starts with the username, I'd explode the line, then increment a counter something like `$count[$words[0]] += (count($words)-1)` in your second loop but there may be more to it that you haven't mentioned.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/0bM6Y (replace the foreach used in the example, without your while loop over your file data, on your own.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go a more general approach. This way you can analyze all users. Using a blacklist, just exclude them.

- First go through all the lines and match for username and text.
- Rebuild data structure by iterating and counting up using a blacklist.

*The blacklist is formatted like this, because finding keys is faster than finding values.*

```
$input = <<<'_TEXT'
<Amanda> Hi there, how are you?
<Jack> Hi, im fine
<Jack> see you later
<John> Hello World, my friends!
<Daniel> Foo!
_TEXT;
preg_match_all('/^<([^>]+)>(.*?)$/m', $input, $matches);

$blacklist = ['Amanda' => 1, 'Jack' => 1];
$words = [];
foreach ($matches[2] as $index => $match) {
    $user = $matches[1][$index];
    if (isset($blacklist[$user])) {
        continue;
    }
    $words[$user] = ($words[$user] ?? 0) + str_word_count($match);
}
print_r($words);
```

```
Array
(
    [John] => 4
    [Daniel] => 1
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. May I know how does this ?? works ($words[$user] ?? 0)

Comment: Sure, this is the null coalesce operator. It is equivalent to `isset($words[$user]) ? $words[$user] : 0`; So it checks **if** the key exists, if it does it returns the value, **else** 0.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding this could be a possible solution.

```
// Input
$input = "<Amanda> Hi there, how are you?\n<Jack> Hi, im fine \n <Jack> see you later";

// Initialize counters
$amandaCount = 0;
$jackCount = 0;

// Split input by lines
$lines = explode("\n", $input);

// Loop over lines
foreach ($lines as $line) {
  // Remove user tags
  $cleanLine = preg_replace("/<.+?>/", "", $line);
  
  // Split line into words
  $words = str_word_count($cleanLine, 1);
  
  // Count words per user
  if (strpos($line, "<Amanda>") !== false) {
    $amandaCount += count($words);
  } elseif (strpos($line, "<Jack>") !== false) {
    $jackCount += count($words);
  }
}

// Output
echo "Amanda: $amandaCount\n";
echo "Jack: $jackCount\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

I would implement the blacklisted names in the regex to filter them out as early as possible.

A negated lookahead ensures that Amanda and Jack are excluded. `(?!Amanda>|Jack>)`

The `m` pattern modifier changes the meaning of the `^` ("start of string" anchor) to be the "start of a line" anchor.

Parentheses around the name subpattern will create capture group 1 (accessible as element `[1]`). `\K` will restart the fullstring match, so the space-delimited words substring will be accessible via `[0]`.

Use destructuring syntax in the `foreach()` for convenient variables.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iskZB))

```
preg_match_all(
    '/^<((?!Amanda>|Jack>)[^>]+)> \K.+/m',
    $chat,
    $matches,
    PREG_SET_ORDER
);
$result = [];
foreach ($matches as [$words, $name]) {
    $result[$name] = ($result[$name] ?? 0) + str_word_count($words);
}
var_export($result);
```